# Permission when setting up sftp on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, chmod

Okay, so I'm setting up an sftp server on Ubuntu 20.04. There will be multiple users accessing the box through sftp and I want each one of them to only have access to their own directory. I don't want them to be able to see, modify, download, etc. any other user's directories or files. Basically a chroot jail scenario.

I ended up with a folder structure like this:

```
/var/
|-- sftp/
    |-- user1/
        |-- uploads/
            |-- file1
            |-- file2
    |-- user2/
        |-- upoads/
            |-- filea
            |-- fil2b
```

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains this:

```
Match Group mygroup
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no

Match User user1
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/user1

Match User user2
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/user2
```

It basically works but there are a few aspects that I don't understand.

Apparently when you are configuring the sftp server in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you must set `ChrootDirectory` to a directory that is owned by `root`. I guess that's fine but for some reason that seems to mean that when a user connects via sftp they can't do anything in the directory they are initially placed in. For example, when `user1` connects they go to `/var/sftp/user1` but they can't do anything in the folder. They have to go to `/var/sftp/user1/uploads` where they can upload and download things. I set it up so that `user1` owns the `/var/sftp/user1/uploads` directory. That's kind of inconvenient for the user. Is there any way to let them work directly in the root directory?

Another thing I'm not sure about is that you are required to assign permission 755 to the `/var/sftp/user1` and `/var/sftp/user1/uploads` folders. It seems that if I use any other permission (even 777) it doesn't work. Why is that? What's so special about 755?